# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined. Promises?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I think I am having a few issues understanding how promises work. I understand that $http, $q, and $resource all return promises. But accessing the data that promises return, now that is the question.

I keep getting an error that doesn't quite make sense to me.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.
```

**Service**

```
this.method = function(args){
  return $http.get(url)
    .success(function(data.somePropertyOfReturnedDataBecauseItsJSON){
      console.log('It got the data');
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.getData = function(){
 service.method(args)
   .then(function(data){
     $someObject.someProperty = data;
   });
}
```

Any advice and explanations would be fantastic!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"this.method" raises a red flag for me.
What's "this" in this context?

Your full service should be something like this:

```
myModule.factory('myService', function($http){
    var service = {};
    var url = 'www.foobar.com/servicepath';

    service.method = function(args){ // Where are you using these args?
      return $http.get(url)
        .success(function(data){
          console.log('It got the data');
        });
    };

    return service;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't that be myModule.factory(...) ?

Comment: ngModule.service(...) takes a constructor as a second argument. So in that case, "this.method = [...]" would work as expected.

Comment: @HankScorpio: What jlowcs said for the this. The arguments are not used in this example, just placeholders to convey the general idea of what I am trying to do. Why are you returning the service? In the service? If I am calling the service from a controller? My full service, is something like that, but I cut the rest of it out to address the important issue which is the error I am receiving.

Comment: *edited* Changed it to a factory. I'm not totally clear on the difference between service and factory in angular.
Either way, I wanted to point to "this" and ask you to make sure it's the correct context.

Comment: @HankScorpio: It is in the correct context. Any ideas on why I am receiving that error? Or any explanations as to promises via my code and why it's not returning data?

Comment: Looks to me like it should work, so I'm more curious about the code you haven't posted.

Comment: The only thing I haven't posted is my module declaration, service declaration, and dependency injections.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a promise from the service, you can chain promises and then use then like this:

```
this.method = function(args){
  return $http.get(url)
    .success(function(data.somePropertyOfReturnedDataBecauseItsJSON){
      return some value // what you return here will be the results of then
    });
}


$scope.getData = function(){
 service.method(args)
   .then(function(data){
     data here is what you return from the promise
   });
}
```

Comment: @JslsAwesome: How is this different from my original code?

Comment: You does not return nothing from the promise, you only console log, so you does not have the method "then" cause it is not return promise, you need to return some value.